# if div's overflow-y reach bottom continue scrolling on body?

Tags: jquery, css

i find very annoying when create a div with `overflow-y: scroll` if the user reach the end of this div will have to move the mouse outside  to continue scrolling on the main page.
Basically i need something like this: [example](http://www.matchesfashion.com/intl/products/Saint-Laurent-Distressed-checked-cotton-blend-flannel-shirt--1078114)
If you open "shop the look" and scroll on this div until bottom you will see that then will continue scrolling on the main page.
Is it possible with pure CSS or needs also jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Not replicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing you want, is the default behaviour (at least it is in chrome).

So i have 2 divs side by side, one has content overflow.

When i scroll down and reach the end of the content the window begins scrolling.

```
.div1 {
  float:left;
  background: steelblue;
  height: 150vh;
  width: 50%;
}

.div2 {
  float:right;
  background: indianred;
  height: 75vh;
  width: 50%;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/9pne7dn5/1/

Comment: This is the same in IE11 Edge and FF (though a bit of a delay before the window begins scrolling).

Comment: you are right, the problem was some extension in Chrome!but very strange that the other website was not affected (maybe different way of coding)thank you

Comment: just out of curiosity, what was the extension causing the issue?

Comment: Might not being an extension after all, i disable all 1 by 1 and still the same problem. I also wanted to know if it was a problem with an extension. The only way was to start Chrome in Incognito mode that i guess most of the settings come to default, then scrolling was ok. I guess i will need to reset Chrome, it's been long time i use.

Comment: what about in other broswers? edge or firefox maybe?

Comment: In chrome address bar type   chrome://flags/   there are some settings about half way down to do with scrolling. mine are set to: 'smoothscrolling:Default', 'Overlay scrollbars:Default'. Not sure but maybe these affect it?